# add a linked python import in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio solution with two Python projects. How do I import a file from one project into another? For example, I want to import **file_a.py** inside of **file_b.py**

```
solution
 |-> porject_a
 |    |-> file_a.py
 |-> project_b
      |-> file_b.py
```

I've already modified the pyproj file in project_b to include,

```
<Compile Include="..\project_a\file_a.py">
    <Link>project_a\file_a.py</Link>
</Compile>
```

Visual Studio at this point has no warning and appears to see the file however when I run **file_b.py**, python errors out. My code inside of **file_b.py** is `import file_a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project_b, right click on "Search_Paths" and select "Add Folder to Search Paths". Select the porject_a folder. When you run, it should now work.

[image: add folder search path]